# Color picker for taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have created custom taxonomy for my CPT. Now I want to create color for category types but I am failed I guess.  I can see color picker in edit category and I can also pick it but after I save the category and re-checking again it show no color.

Below code works for general post categories but not for custom post type categories.

I am not sure where do i do the mistake

[image]

My tax registration :

```
$labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Categories', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Category', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Categories'),
        'all_items' => __('All Categories'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Category'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Category:'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Category'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Category'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Category Name'),
        'menu_name' => __('Category'),
);

$args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blog-category'),
);

register_taxonomy('blog-category', array('blog'), $args);
```

Code for function.php to create a label in category types to pick color

```
add_action( 'blog-category_edit_form_fields', 'blog_category_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
function blog_category_taxonomy_custom_fields($tag) {
    ?>

        <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top">
            <label for="excerpt"><?php _e('Color'); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="_term_meta[color]" class="color-picker"
                   value="<?php echo get_term_meta($tag->term_id, 'color', true) ?>">

            <script>
                jQuery(function ($) {
                    $('.color-picker').wpColorPicker();
                })
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <?php
}
```

Comment: Please see this link : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112866/adding-colorpicker-field-to-category

Comment: This is working only for General post categories but now for custom taxonomies. My code also works for general posts categories.

Comment: your taxonomy `slug` is the issue i think so please change it this one `blog-category`

Comment: @raju_eww yeah I thought so too earlier and i changed it to `blog-type` but I am still facing same issue.

Comment: whats the slug of your custom taxonomy?

Comment: Under `blog-type` I have `legal-alert` slug